# Is a temporary variable needed when just passing the pointer to the first element of a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the following function to append a double value at the end of a linked list.

```c
void deappendlinked(dNODE *head,double value){
  while(head!=NULL){
    if(head->next==NULL){
      break;
    }
    head=head->next;
  }
  dNODE *newElement=memalloc(sizeof(dNODE));
  newElement->data=value;
  newElement->next=NULL;
  head->next=newElement;
}
```

It receives the head, i.e., the address of the first element of the linked list, which I iterate through to the end.

As I'm not passing a pointer of a pointer, I do not need a temporary variable to hold the value of the head, correct? (I.e. I can just do what I did – at least it works.)

Comment: No, you don't need. `head` is a local variable and won't change outside the function.

Comment: @kaylum good point! I made sure it's never NULL. When I create the linked list, it starts with a value; if it can't the program aborts\

Comment: not entirely sure what you're asking ... but `head->` is the same as `(*head).`, so you're dereferencing the pointer and modifying what it points to, meaning when you leave the function the changes you made to what it points to will persist. There's no other temp variable required.

Comment: If this could start on an "empty" (e.g. `NULL`) list, might help to return the new head as a pointer.

Comment: @tadman But, if the function creates a new list, then it would need to take a pointer-to-pointer argument (or have a non void return type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *As I'm not passing a pointer of a pointer, I do not need a temporary variable to hold the value of the head, correct?*

That is correct. The function will receive a *copy* of the pointer passed by the calling module. In that module, the value of that pointer will *not* be changed by your function (i.e. it will remain pointing at the head of the list).

As an aside, even if *you* know that your passed `head` value will not (read: *should* not) be `NULL`, it is still better to add a check for that, in case a future editor of your code does something silly.

Also, your `while` loop can be much simplified:

```c
void deappendlinked(dNODE *head,double value) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        // Optional error message?
        return;
    }

    while (head->next != NULL) head = head->next;

    dNODE *newElement=memalloc(sizeof(dNODE));
    newElement->data=value;
    newElement->next=NULL;
    head->next=newElement;
}
```